# Update join with a one to many relationship

Tags: mysql, sql-update, database-table

I have a table of users that looks like this:

**USERS**

```
userid | email | action | actiontimestamp
```

And another table of some user actions (login, logout, etc.) that looks like this:

**USER_ACTIONS**

```
actionid | userid | action | actiontimestamp
```

I need to be able to update the USERS table action and actiontimestamp values with a single query where it uses the latest row from the USER_ACTIONS table. Is this possible?

Comment: Please add sample input and output data.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE users u
  JOIN ( SELECT DISTINCT
                userid, 
                FIRST_VALUE(action) OVER (PARTITION BY userid ORDER BY actiontimestamp DESC) action,
                MAX(actiontimestamp) OVER (PARTITION BY userid) actiontimestamp 
        ) ua USING (userid)
SET u.action = ua.action,
    u.actiontimestamp = ua.actiontimestamp
```

PS. Version 8+ needed. For more ancient versions use single-table UPDATE with 2 correlated queries.